# pytest, how to run a command at exit, no matter the testsuite run

Tags: python, pytest

During my tests, I'm creating a lot of tables dynamically with SQLAlchemy, which I'd love to clean up once all tests have been run.

SQLAlchemy doesn't allow to recreate a table once it has been defined.

I tried using `import atexit` to run a `drop table` script before exiting, however it seems that it is not run with pytest.

Any advice?

Comment: How do you exit the script?

Comment: @Parvat.R pytest exits on his own once all tests in the module have been run. I don't run any sys.exit on my own

Comment: Have you tried a session-based autouse fixture? Implementing `pytest_sessionfinish` in your `conftest.py` is another possibility.